# Counting number of rows with a parameter

Tags: php, mysql, count, rows

I have this query:

```
$queryf = "SELECT * FROM classifieds 
WHERE city IN ('$cities') AND state IN ('$states') 
ORDER BY FIELD (city, '$cities'), datetime DESC";
```

$cities is an array of nearby cities within 5 miles. Same with states.

Basically, I want to search my user information table that has user-inputted information (like a craigslist/classifieds type table), and COUNT the number of rows PER CITY. So that it's possible to echo something like:

```
10 results found within 5 miles:
Dublin, CA (8 records)
Hayward, CA (2 records)
```

Does anyone know how I'd be able to track/return the amount of rows where the city is identical?

Comment: String concatenating an array doesn't work like that.

Comment: Hi. Your negative remark did not help me. These statements seem to be more advanced than what a basic user would know, from my intermediate perspective. Either you're misunderstanding the question or you're having a bad day. Thank you though.

Comment: Neither! In fact I understand you perfectly, _and_ I had a great day thanks. I'm sorry if you didn't understand my comment, but I'm here to tell the facts not to help you. My point is that is definitely _not_ your real query (if `$cities` is _really_ "an array", then you're searching for a city called "Array", because that's how arrays get converted to strings in PHP); and if it's not your real query, then you're wasting our time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `GROUP BY`, together with `COUNT()` should give you what you need:

```
$queryf = "SELECT *, count(classifieds.id) AS num_cities FROM classifieds 
WHERE city IN ('$cities') AND state IN ('$states') 
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY FIELD (city, '$cities'), datetime DESC";
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

MySQL has a whole bunch of functions and keywords for this sort of *aggregation*.

Read [the documentation for your `SELECT` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html), especially when it talks about the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT city, COUNT(1) AS count FROM classifieds 
WHERE city IN ('$cities') AND state IN ('$states') 
GROUP BY city
```